# Question about defining resource layout id in the activity/fragment constructor

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, androidx

I keep reading everywhere that you can now use the activity/fragment constructor to define the layout id with AndroidX, but none answer my question.

What if you have others things to do in Activity's onCreate or Fragment's onCreateView ? Can you still use this new constructor ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**For Activities**

Yes, it just means that the Activity will call `setContentView()` with the layout ID you provide as part of calling `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)`. Otherwise, you can proceed as normal in your `onCreate()`.

**For Fragments**

Generally, if using the layout ID constructor, you'd want to move your code from `onCreateView()` to `onViewCreated()`, which is passed the View that was created by `onCreateView()`.

Of course, if you *do* want to override `onCreateView()` for some reason, you'd want to call  `super.onCreateView()` to retrieve the inflated layout corresponding with the layout ID you provided to the constructor argument.